# Item isn't displayed even though it should

Tags: c++, qt

In qt's proxy model - QSortFilterProxyModel I'm setting:

```
proxy_model_->setFilterRegExp("*.txt");
   regex.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
```

Yet, when I pass file "1.txt" this isn't displayed on a listView. Is there anything else am I suppose to do in order to achieve that?

Comment: Command in which container you're displaying the data?

Comment: @v01d data are displayed in listView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
proxy_model_->setFilterWildcard("*.txt");
```

instead.

Comment: thanks, this doesn't work on its own though. I've realized that on top of that one has to call proxy->invalidate() every time items are added; Will accept though.